# How to hide ios scrollbar in phonegap

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want not to show the scrolling indicator in my ios phonegap application but dont know how to hide it. Is there a css, javascript or native editing way?
How to not show the scrolling indicator in the ios phonegap application?
 Any way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While developing my application, i actually wanted to include the scroll bars so i had to include these two lines of code:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
```

What you might want to try is to set the overflow scrolling to :none and try to disable the webkit-transform somehow...

if you are using jquery mobile, you can try something like this:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
  $.support.touchOverflow = false;
  $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = false;
});
```

check out [this page](http://filamentgroup.com/tests/popup/docs/pages/touchoverflow.html) for more info